# outputting to a label in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently running a script that outputs results into a textbox however I would like to use a different control to display the results

here are snippets . . .
thank you!
This is what I have that works . . .

```
 <input type="text" id="dice2" /><br/><br/>
    $("dice2").value = die1.getValue2();
```

This isn't working . . .

```
 <span id="dice2">&nbsp;</span><br /><br />
    $("dice2").value = die1.getValue2();
```

I would like the javascript/html equivalent to outputting to a label in C#.
Thanks Again!

Comment: Can you give us the HTML you're using? What is `die1`? What is `dice2`?

Comment: if dice2 is id of your element then put $('#dice2') else if it is class name then put $('.dice2')

Comment: Could your jQuery selector be wrong? For example $("#dice2") if dice2 is an ID or $(".dice2") if dice2 is a class.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery, `.val()` is a function used to get and set the value of an input. and don't forget to put the # before element id
`$("#dice2").val($("#dice1").val());`

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed the '#':

```
$("dice2").value = die1.getValue2();
```

should be (for ID):

```
$("#dice2").value = die1.getValue2();
```

For (classes):

```
$(".dice2").value = die1.getValue2();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all **this does not require jQuery and you can easily achieve this with vanilla JS**.

Second of all, `<input>` tags have different attributes than `<span>` tags and need to be treated separately.

To get/set what is inside of an `<input>` tag just call:

`document.getElementById('my-input').value`

To get/set what is inside of a `<span>` tag call:

`document.getElementByTagName('span').innerText` (or `.innerHTML` if you don't want the HTML to be decoded)

So if you wanted to get the text from a textbox and put it in a span tag you could do the following:

```
var inputTextbox = document.getElementById('my-input-textbox'),
    spanResult = document.getElementById('my-resulting-span');

spanResult.innerHTML = inputTextbox.value;
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you liked answer you should upvote and select it as the correct answer so others can learn as well.